# Logon script not running

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, scripting, group-policy, login

I tried making a logon script to map some network drives since I need more than homedir. I have applied  to script to "logon" in a GPO on server 2008, but it does not run on the PC when I logon.
When I make a Gpresult -r it show as applied but it never ran the script. I tried running the script manually and that works fine.

In Event Viewer in windows 7 it show an error "Event ID 1129" with this text in the general tap:

> The processing of Group Policy failed because of lack of network connectivity to a domain controller. This may be a transient condition. A success message would be generated once the machine gets connected to the domain controller and Group Policy has succesfully processed. If you do not see a success message for several hours, then contact your administrator.

Comment: Is this computer connecting over wireless?

Comment: nope it is wired connection and it get the gpo just not the script :S and there is some 2nd gpo with screensaver settings and stuff and that is applied right on the pc without problems.

Comment: Why not use Group Policy Preferences for Drive Mappings instead: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/01/07/using-group-policy-preferences-to-map-drives-based-on-group-membership.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is curious.

You can try group policy setting:

computer config\admin templates\system\logon\always wait for the network at computer startup and logon

It does slow down PC startup, but it's helped me get login scripts to work in the past.

Comment: This is not necessary for GPP drive mapping extension.